# Typescript interface key value linkage

Tags: typescript

### code

```
  interface StoreActions {
    setUser: string
    action1: string[]
    action2: { test: string }
  }

  interface ActionsH extends AnyAction {
    type: keyof StoreActions
    // data:???
  }
```

The value of the attribute `type` of ActionsH is the key of type StoreActions

### Expect

- When type = 'setUser', the type of data is `string`
- When type = 'action1', the type of data is `string[]`
- When type = 'action2', the type of data is `{ test: string }`

### Is it possible to achieve it? How to achieve?

Comment: Would ` interface ActionsH<T extends keyof StoreActions>{
    type: T,
    data: StoreActions[T],
  }` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of options here.

1. Use a [discriminated union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions) of all available types. You can generate the union with a mapped type. This is probably the better solution since TypeScript will often be able to narrow the type. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZQgQQWYDEAZ2QG8BYAKGVuWIjAFUGoAuesKUAc2ruSICRAIwdiXXgG0AuvzpDCIAEwcyySBPGSQPZAF9qhqtTABPAA4oAsnADWEJiCUAeACoA+ZAF5y82lIA0sigyA5mGDDIbjJqGpYQHIEANMgAJnBgcBxuQTIGRlLhkdFyJuWgkLCIKDggZnjCIH40dBhgABbQHADkCBgAtgNEyBZQGFZQBBCknZmCADYLgvhKxAASyAMQAwBG0KQdcABuED1G1KYJyI1rm762Dk6u6Fi4q0TEXgBkN-W3RCAA)

   ```
   interface StoreActions {
       setUser: string
       action1: string[]
       action2: { test: string }
   }

   type MakeUnion<T> = {
       [K in keyof T]: { type: K, data: T[K] }
   }[keyof T]


   interface AnyAction {
       other: 'common properties that all actionsH members have'
   }

   type ActionsH = MakeUnion<StoreActions> & AnyAction
   ```
2. Make the interface generic and use the key from the generic to set the type of the data property. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=14&pc=2#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMpgPZQgQQWYDEAZ2QG8BYAKGVuWIjAFUGoAuesKUAc2ruSICRAIwdiXXgG0AuvzpDCIAEwcyySBPGSQPZAF9qhqtVCRYiFDhABPPMJDl5tDGAAW0DgHIEGALZ+RMgADlAYwdAEEKTucGCCADYJgvhKxAASyH4QfgBG0KRucABuEF5G1Kbg0PBIyPZK6QA8ANLIEAAekCAAJqQA1hA2GDBomNgNRMQAfO1dEL2k1napQZQ0dGA2ERwtzsg9cXAc6Fi4qyRSLXJU+kA)

   ```
   interface StoreActions {
       setUser: string
       action1: string[]
       action2: { test: string }
   }

   interface AnyAction {
       other: 'common properties that all actionsH members have'
   }

   interface ActionH<K extends keyof StoreActions> extends AnyAction {
       type: K
       data: StoreActions[K]
   }
   ```

Comment: I use scenario 2 and add
``` 
interface StoreProps {
    dispatch: <T extends keyof StoreActions>(options: ActionsH<T>) => void
  }
```
is work for me